# display bytes greater than 0x7f

Tags: c#-4.0

I'd like to connect my program to a serial port & to show the received data from the serial port. I successfully did that, but I have a problem.

I'd like to convert the string shown in the window into a stream of bits

I followed [How could I get the bits from a string in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655830/how-could-i-get-the-bits-from-a-string-in-c/655844#655844)

& my problem is what to do to show a byte like `0xAA`, it's greater than `7f` the maximum value of the ascii characters

I'm developing a program using C# language, I'd like to connect it to a serial port & to show the received data from the serial port,I successfully did that, but I have a problem, I'd like to convert the string shown in the window into a stream of bits I followed How could I get the bits from a string in C#?

& my problem is what to do to show a byte like `0xAA`, it's greater than `7f` the maximum value of the ASCII characters

```
public partial class mm_dig_ctrl : Form
{
    public mm_dig_ctrl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!MySerP.IsOpen)
        {
            MySerP.Open();
            TB_Port_Status.Text = "Port is Opened";
        }
        else
        {
            TB_Port_Status.Text = "Port is Busy";
        }
        MySerP.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

    }

    public delegate void AddDataDelegate(String rxstring);
    public AddDataDelegate myDelegate;
    private void mm_dig_ctrl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.myDelegate = new AddDataDelegate(AddDataMethod);
    }
    public void AddDataMethod(String myString)
    {

        TBRX_Read.AppendText(myString);
    }
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        String rxstring,to_show;
        rxstring = MySerP.ReadExisting();
        to_show  = GetBits(rxstring);
        TBRX_Read.Invoke(this.myDelegate, new object[] { to_show });
        //TBRX_Read.Text += rxstring;
    }

    public string GetBits(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in input)
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

'

Comment: isn't 0xFF the maximum ASCII value? AFAIK, ASCII goes up to 255.

Comment: @ItsGreg ASCII is 0-127... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: If you're sure that 0xAA is a correct value, then you're getting chars of the extended ASCII table (0x00 - 0xFF). In your case 0xAA would be 170(dec) or the eASCII char ¬

Comment: It is really up to you to decide what you want to do. In many cases tools just print HEX for all bytes...

Comment: it didn't print me values greater than 0x7f, how to make the chars to be an in extended asciitable

Comment: I added it to to an answer

Comment: Why do you call the bytes that you get from the serial port a string? Do they represent text? If so which character set and encoding is the device sending them as?

Comment: "Extended ASCII" is not one character set, it's one of a couple dozen—and you have to which one.